# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'breakpoints') in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use breakpoint in Material UI (React Project).
I'm using the v5.0.1 of Material UI

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  gridRight: {
    width: "50%",
    height: "350px",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    opacity: 0.3,
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    color: "white",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      width: "100%",
    },
  },
}));
```

But I got the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'breakpoints')`

I have also tried to use the `ThemeProvider` but the error still exists.
Also, I checked the default usage from Material Ui docs, the error still remains undefined breakpoint.

Full Code

```
import "./welcome.css";
import * as React from "react";
import { Typography, Grid } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  gridRight: {
    width: "50%",
    height: "350px",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    opacity: 0.3,
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    color: "white",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      width: "100%",
    },
  },
}));

const Welcome = () => {
  const PF = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_FOLDER;
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `URL(${PF + "back.jpg"})`,
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        height: "calc(100vh)",
      }}
    >
      <Grid container rowSpacing={1} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <div className={classes.gridLeft}>
            <Typography>Side One </Typography>
          </div>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <div className={classes.gridRight}>
            <Typography>Side Two </Typography>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

Comment: what version of material UI u using? as in few different releases the `makeStyles` import is different

Comment: "@mui/material": "^5.0.2",

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53937137/1868008 the v5 part